# autocommit to main branch with gitlab cicd

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Our project contains a few submodules, and follows the following structure:

```
main_project
    modules/subproject1 (submodule)
    modules/subproject2 (submodule)
    modules/subproject3 (submodule)
```

whenever we raise a MR on any of the subprojects we run the cicd pipeline of the entire project. All our jobs so far have the rule:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

Now I am trying to add one extra job for the CICD to only run whenever there is a commit to the main branch of the submodule in question. My primiary idea is I want to launch an auto commit to `main_project` to update the submodules to point to the new commit of that particular branch.

For now I just want a job to be launched whenever there is a commit that took place to the submodule in question: I have tried to add folloowing job:

```
update_submodules:
  stage: .post
  script:
    - echo "Finished updating submodules - dummy "
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'

  when: always
```

however, it seems that this job is completely ignored - and I have started to wonder if this is at all possible with gitlab? Because this job should be executed independently of the rest of the cicd pipeline (essentially whenever the merge button is pressed it should be executed)

Comment: Try using an actual stage name instead of `.post`.  See if that resolves the issue you're having. I'm assuming by "this job is completely ignored" that you mean no new pipeline runs when you merge the MR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All our jobs so far have the rule: `- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'`

If a pipeline only contains jobs in `.pre` or `.post` stages, the pipeline will not run. Since you mentioned all of your other jobs have this rule, that means that your `update_submodules` job would be the only job present when a branch pipeline runs and because it is in the `.post` stage, the pipeline will not run. As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages):

> If a pipeline contains only jobs in the `.pre` or `.post` stages, it does not run. There must be at least one other job in a different stage.

You can resolve this problem by using an actual stage name rather than `.post` for your `update_submodules` job OR ensuring that at least one other job not in `.post` or `.pre` is included in branch pipelines, which will allow your `.post` job(s) to run.